# Android: what is the inputType for username

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an edit text on my `xml` layout to allow the user to enter his username,like this:

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType=""
                />
```

which type of `inputType` should i use to make the user enter his username, the username contains just letters small letter and capital letter and numbers

Answer (score 18, accepted):

May I suggest [`textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS) it gives you the normal keyboard with the option to display numbers but gets rid of the Android suggestions (they're pretty useless when typing in a username).

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by Hailwood, some users may like the added benefit of the suggestions provided by the Android keyboard. Upon reflection on the matter, perhaps a standard `text` might be more suited for this situation.

It's really a UX matter, you'll have to make a choice here.

Comment: Personal user experience here, but I use my last name as my username for a lot of things (generally things that I have associated with me personally anyway, so it's not a privacy issue), So, having the suggestions there saves me quite a bit of typing!

Comment: Valid observation. Then the default inputType would be more suited. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @Hailwood As Simon points out in his answer, if suggestions are left on, some IMEs will auto insert spaces and auto-capitalize text.

Comment: @DheerajV.S. In addition to screw up with capitalization and spaces, that would fill up the keyboard's dictionary with words which aren't…

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textNoSuggestions"` as some IME/Android-Version combinations seem to ignore `textNoSuggestions` but not `textVisiblePassword`. If suggestions are left on some IME will auto insert spaces or other punctuation and auto-capitalize text which can screw up logins.